# Is there time limit for street parking in Milan on blue bays?

Tags: automobiles, milan

I've been doing some research and see that there is a lot of blue bays around, and it seems like the cost is €1,20 per hour between 8-13 (Mon-Fri) and free for the rest of the day. What I can't figure out is if there is any time limit. If not, could I literally pay 5 * 5 * 1,20 = €30 for the whole week and leave the car there without any worries?

Also, I found an app called EasyPark which allows me to select a duration and pay for the parking. Is there anything I need to display in the car while it's parked? Like a confirmation code or anything?

Comment: For the biggest cities (Milan, Rome, Naples, Turin) parking fares on blue bays **vary** according to the neighborhood. E.g. if you stop in the city border you pay faaaaaaaaaaairly less than next to Colosseum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time limit could be an issue. Not regulatory, but technical. My Italian coworkers confirm that the regulator never mentions time limit on paid parking, *as soon as you pay for it* (their words). The problem really lies in getting a ticket that is valid for the whole week.

I don't have reliable information for Milan, but there are possibly different ways. One is inapplicable. Two of them require being at the ticketing machine, physically.

- One *was* to buy "scratchy" parking tickets. These are being decommissioned in the entire country, and **have been** already decommissioned in Milan. You could basically buy more tickets and scratch them in consecutive date/time boxes to stack them up
- Two is to check how expensive you can buy a single ticket, by compulsively press the "+" button on the ticketing machine until you reach your desired duration or the machine's limit. Don't be surprised if the machine doesn't allow you to buy more than few hours, because average customers stay *short* time
- Third is to try to see if the machine allows you to buy a *future* ticket, so that you can use its menu to select a different start time for your parking. This way you can buy and display a stack of 5 daily tickets
- Fourth is to use a parking app, but registration could be cumbersome and **might** (no reliable info right now) require you to **own** the car, i.e. you can't buy tickets for a rental car or such as you must prove you own that license number

For the city of Milan, considered that you spoke about long-term parking, it could be worth examining a different approach. There are a few hub parkings at largest underground stations, mostly near highways. They offer daily fares and you can pay when you retrieve your car.

Answer (score 6):

The parking regulation in Milan is explained in this page:

[Sosta su Strada](https://www.atm.it/it/ViaggiaConNoi/Auto/Pagine/SostaStrada.aspx) (Italian only)

They don't mention any time limits in the area you're interested in.

They mention the app EasyPark among the [allowed payements methods](https://www.atm.it/it/ViaggiaConNoi/Auto/Pagine/Modalitadipagamento.aspx), stating that the parking controllers shall check in real time that you've paid for the parking. So  you don't have to display anything. Some people use a small piece of paper saying "I am using /APP/" or the like.

PS: note that there are different price areas with different rules. Always refer to the instruction printed on vertical signs.